# Align OpenLayers raster with OS Mapping Vector

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, vector

I have an OS vector map of a town in Ireland. When I load the Google Satellite raster from the OpenLayers plugin, the results are slightly off, by about 2m, probably due to aerial perspective.

I'm trying to digitise information from the Satellite raster onto the OS Mapping and it would be easier if I could force the Satellite raster to move temporarily so they align in that perspective.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have any other data to compare (or screenshot) I assume you are using Irish National Grid? But you are likely to be correct and the raster is slightly misaligned.